# How to change windows settings programmatically?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-11, c++

The following are the categories of settings in windows:

[image]

Each has their own set of sub settings (sometimes nested too), as shown in the following picture:
[image]

Whenever I format my computer I change a lot of settings here and the process is tedious and repetitive and I'd like to automate it.

What I want to know is a way to change these settings programmatically (through c++, powershell, cmd batch, whatever).

I'd like a list of the settings and the respective way to change them programmatically, so that I can make a script that would do something similar to the following pseudocode:

```
Change-Setting --Setting NightLight --Value On -- Strength 60
Change-Setting --Setting Scale --Value 100
Change-Setting --Setting RefreshRate --Value 144.01
...
```

I've searched for this and there doesn't seem to be a lot of information about this topic (which is suprising, because it seems like it could be something a lot of people would try to automate). I've looked into [this](https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/124376-settings-using-powershell-cmd-2.html?s=eb2ad48c591335a9d82873f0056c024e&forcenoajax=1) post, where it is said to look for regestry changes using ProcMon and then detect which changes were made to the registry when activating a specific setting (which could be more than one) and then use it to change the value myself. After that, a restart to the computer is needed.

This process would take ages, like a really long time to not be worth it. Surely there's an easier way to achieve what I'm trying to?

I'm using windows 11.

Comment: You can change the majority and likely all settings through a group policy. Why don’t you export the keys associated with those policies and set them with a single registry file?

Comment: Specifically, find each item's setting in the Registry, export each key, and combine all the .reg files into one, if desired.

Comment: I find registry changes by exporting the registry before and again after making changes, I then use the Compare function in Notepad++ to diff the exports. I find it is a little simpler than using Procmon. I would also appreciate "a list of the settings and the respective way to change them programmatically" but I am not sure one exists.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also trying to automate this

Comment: @MaxProgramming I did not. I kinda gave up on it. If you really want to do that, I recommend syncing the settings in windows, but if you're asking this here, I presume you don't